# Find Material of IPersistentEntity

Tags: xbim

I have list of `IPersistEntity` instances, that can be meshed, it means each of them implements one of these interfaces: `IIfcFaceBasedSurfaceModel`, `IIfcShellBasedSurfaceModel`, `IIfcConnectedFaceSet`, `IIfcTriangulatedFaceSet`, `IIfcFacetedBrep`.

And I want to find for each of this instance corresponding `IIfcMaterial` or `IIfcSurfaceStyle`.

I spend good amount of time digging in the repository but didn't find the way to do this. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert your entities to `IfcObjectDefinition`, you'll be able to get the material from there.

```
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
      var definition = entity as IfcObjectDefinition;
      var material = definition.Material as IIfcMaterial;
    }
```